# IE aborts html5 video load for 1 file

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

I am trying to create a front end webpage to host tutorial/troubleshoot videos for commonly occurring questions in my company. I am using html5 and am trying to have the page work in the latest versions of IE FF and Chrome. The webpage works in all three except that IE is is acting a bit strange. I have multiple mp4 videos of IE however only one seems to be abort every time. I was wondering how I could fix this issue.

Here is a sample of my code. I'm pretty sure this is all correct.

```
 <div id="video0" class="videos">
        <a  href="How_to_Compress_a_Folder.mp4">Alternate Link</a><br/>
        <video  controls id="player0" class="players">
            <source src="How_to_Compress_a_Folder.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="How_to_Compress_a_Folder.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
        </div>

        <div id="video1" class="videos" >
        <a href="How_to_Map_a_Network_Drive_on_Windows_7.mp4"> Alternate Link</a><br/>
        <video id="player1" controls class="players">
            <source src="How_to_Map_a_Network_Drive_on_Windows_7.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        </div>
```

How to map a Network Drive loads and plays properly but How to Compress a folder does not any suggestions. I've tried to convert the .ogv file to mp4 to see if that would work as well but it does not. Again it is just this one file that is giving me issues. I would like to avoid rerecording the video because there is no guarantee this issue will not occur again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually simple. there wasn't a problem with the code but the file itself. It appears that the person who created the videos recorded some of them as mp4 and others as avi then converted to mp4. He originally used Miro Converter to covert them to mp4 which is why it didn't work. He then tried a different converter (not sure which one) and it was fine.

Comment: Well done. It's generally a good strategy to try opening the video file directly in the browser. If it doesn't play, you don't have to mess about with your HTML and scripts.